# install in ProgramData folder using NSIS

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I'd like to install some application data in `C:\ProgramData` folder using `nsis installer`. I'd like to avoid hardcoding it, because it may not be on `C: drive`.

The documentation https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html doesn't have any constant that defines `ProgramData`. What is the `nsis` way of installing in `ProgramData` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft moved and renamed some of the special folders in Vista. `%ProgramData%` is [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl) and you can get that path in NSIS:

```
Section
SetShellVarContext all
MessageBox MB_OK "$LocalAppData"
SetOutPath "$LocalAppData\MyAppsData" 
File /r mydata\*.*
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Does SetShellVarContext only apply to the section itself or is it global?

Comment: @Smile4ever It is global and last until you change it again. Ideally you just set it in .onInit. Set it to "current" if installing for a single user or "all" if installing to $ProgramFiles.

Comment: According to the docs you would use `$APPDATA` https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Best_practices

Comment: @HackSlash That depends on what kind of data. Read-only data for all users goes in %ProgramData%. Roaming user settings go in $AppData and local/cache data goes in $LocalAppData.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetKnownFolderPath`:

```
GetKnownFolderPath $0 {62AB5D82-FDC1-4DC3-A9DD-070D1D495D97} ; FOLDERID_ProgramData
MessageBox MB_OK $0
```